# Multiple images in a Div CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple css Box layout with images that float left, and it works fine when I place them in seperate div's :

```
<div id="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="photos/image1.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150>
    <figcaption>Watch #1</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </div>

<div id="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="photos/image2.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150>
    <figcaption>Watch #2</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>

<div id="images">

    <img src="photos/image3.jpg" alt="Photo" width="150" height="150">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#images {
    float:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:5px;
    height:220px;
    width:220px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;

}
```

But I receive an error: "duplicate ID reference" I've googled and its told me this definitely should be avoided,

but everytime I add all the images into the div my code doesnt work and they just end up everywhere. Can anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: IDs have to be unique in the document. Just use `<div class="images">` and `.images` as the CSS selector.

Comment: change #images to .images and use it as a class for div's

Comment: You can use ID one time in one page so if you need many time same css then use class..

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Sorry I'm really new to html/css, whats the difference between <div id="images" and <div class="images"?

Comment: @AlexP2014 an ID is a unique identifier and, by definition, can not be repeated in a single document. A class name is an attribute that can be re-used and combined with other class names like `<div class="news breaking sticky">` where every class name has its own styles (for example: `.breaking { background:red; } .sticky { position:fixed; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID is a unique attribute of an element, which can only be used once on a page.

What you can do to solve your issue, is the following:

**WORKING DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daq37/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Photo" />
        <figcaption>Watch #1</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Photo" />
        <figcaption>Watch #2</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Photo" />
        <figcaption>Watch #3</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.images {
    float:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:5px;
    height:220px;
    width:220px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

I took the liberty to add `<div class="clearfix"></div>`, which makes sure no other elements on the page (underneath these three div's) get shifted because of the used float.

Comment: awesome thanks for your help! just quickly, is there any reason why a seperate div is needed for each image? Howcome when I place them all under the same <div> it doesnt work?
 thanks !

Comment: I used your lay-out to create this solution. If I'm correct, you can just put all images in one div without a problem. Look at this [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daq37/1/) to see the result, it looks exactly the same. Notice that I've removed the separate `div`'s, and changed the CSS selector to be applied on the `figure`, and **NOT** on the `<div class="images">`, as that would not work anymore.

Comment: awesome cheers, just quickly, howcome it would not work anymore if you didnt change it to figure?

Comment: @AlexP2014 Technically the floating would still work, but you wouldn't be able to see it. The reason for that is the fact that you only have one div, and it's automatically positioned on the left, so `float:left` would have no visible result, even though it is applied. `float:left` becomes visible when applied to 2 or more elements in your page, in this case the figures. To clarify, here's an example with `float:left` applied to the parent div: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daq37/2/). The parent floats correctly, but that's not your desired result. (I added extra parent div's for clarity)

Comment: @AlexP2014 If you compare the JSFiddle of my first comment with the one of my last but this one, you can see the float works for both the `figure`'s and the parent `div`s. See the difference? I hope this helps you understand `floating` a little bit better.

Answer (score 2):

try this code  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwzxb)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way is to change the id's in the elements for classes, so:

```
<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="photos/image1.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150>
    <figcaption>Watch #1</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Then your css to match

```
.images {
    float:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:5px;
    height:220px;
    width:220px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
```

ID's should be unique on a page, whereas classes can be duplicated as much as you want.

Comment: No worries. This explains the differences between the two fairly well http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

The ID attribute is a **unique identifier** and therefore [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). You currently have three elements with the same ID; this is invalid. Instead of using an ID you can use a class instead:

```
<div class="images">
    ...
</div>
```

And change your CSS to use a class selector instead of an ID selector:

```
.images {
    ...
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks very much, just quickly, does that mean I can have all my images under the same class? or is it better practice to split them out into seperate <div class>? Cheers

Comment: @AlexP2014 That depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve. I imagine what you need here though is just one `div` element to wrap all your `figure` elements within.

Comment: Just basically making a simple CSS Box layout with images, 6 images to be exact. so I should just do the <div> for each image/figure?

Comment: @AlexP2014 your `figure` elements themselves could be styled like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `#images` to `.images` and use it as a class for div's like this:

```
.images {
    float:left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:5px;
    height:220px;
    width:220px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <img src="photos/image1.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150>
    <figcaption>Watch #1</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An id must be unique in a page. Use a class if you want to describe a group of elements.

```
why we should not use id selector two times in a page while its working fine.
```

You are making an error and depending on every browser that will ever view the page to compensate for it. You can't be sure they all will.

try using class instead like

```
.images{
/*Your Css*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the "duplicate ID reference" because you use the same ID more than once. You will want to use class for that instead.

You also need to close your image-tags with `</img>`

Here is a fiddle that shows what I've changed: http://jsfiddle.net/litari/rWSGS/

Comment: `img` tags are self-closing. You'd use `<img ... />`, not `<img></img>`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yeah, either works as long as he closes the tag.

Comment: No. `<img ...>` is exactly the same as `<img ...></img>` because the invalid `</img>` tag would be completely omitted leaving you with just `<img ...>`.